# what is wrong with my cord(upload file to django)

Tags: python, django

What's wrong with my code? It is just uploading file with django. I read in the django documentation and followed the same example, I think.

model.py

```
class OverWriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove("C:\...\_media/excel", name)
            return name


class Upload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='excel/', blank=True, storage=OverWriteStorage())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class ModelUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ['title','file_upload']
```

view.py

```
def excel(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ModelUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = ModelUpload()

    excelTemp = dict(excel['tag'].value_counts().sort_index())

    return render(request, 'single_pages/excel.html',{
        'form': form,
        'excelTemp': excelTemp,

    })
```

My HTML:

```
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form | crispy}}
                    <button name="choice" value="{{ upload.file }}">upload</button>
```

My error message:

```
TypeError at /excel/
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'


During handling of the above exception (expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType), another exception occurred:

form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You only return the `name` in the branch here – if the file doesn't exist, you implicitly return None.

```
class OverWriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove("C:\...\_media/excel", name)
            return name
```

De-indent that last line.

```
class OverWriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove("C:\...\_media/excel", name)
        return name
```

However, I'd advise you against an overwriting storage in the first place – it's a fine recipe for data loss.

Comment: thanks! AKX i solved problem! file is uploaded!! and sadly I got a new error message  remove() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given) i dont know it mean but thank you very much